# Как написать бат-файл, который добавляет в исключение localhost

Tags: bat

Написал вот таким вот образом:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride /t REG_SZ /d "<local>" /f
```

Работает не совсем корректно. Он удаляет ранее записанные исключения. Мне нужно, чтобы он не трогал исключения, которые были, а просто `localhost` добавлял в исключение.

Comment: Это придётся выгрузить в файл текущее значение, выделить его из созданного файла, и сформировать строку выполнения, добавив к текущему значению требуемое (а по-хорошему - сперва проверить на присутствие, может, оно там уже есть). Подобное лучше реализовывать "более продвинутым" скриптингом. Скажем, VBS...

Answer (score 1):

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

@set pt="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
@set v="ProxyOverride"
@set proxy=my host

@for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('@reg query %pt% /v %v%^|@find/i"Reg_SZ"') do (
@set proxy=%%a;%proxy%
@set proxy=!proxy:~31!
)
@reg add %pt% /v %v% /f /d "%proxy%"
@setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

Comment: Команда "set proxy=!proxy:~31! " обрезает строку на 31 символ слева, чтобы из строки запроса значения параметра реестра удалить ненужные символы. Для разных редакций Windows (En,RUS,etc.) выводимая строка может оказаться разной длины. Возможно, количество символов придется подбирать в зависимости от версии.